# SQL to increment (not replace) all user balances on super large table between row x & y while not truncating the balance table

Tags: sql, postgresql, increment

Imagine I have a supremely large transaction transaction table, that grows every minute:

### `transaction` table

| id | userId | quantity | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | user0 | 1 | item1 |
| 1 | user1 | -1 | item1 |
| 2 | user0 | -1 | item1 |
| 3 | user1 | 1 | item1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I will need to count balances every few minutes, so i would run one (presumably very long) query that gets us "current" to generate the initial values of the `balance` table, and perhaps store "last calculated transactionId" in a diff table, so that subsequent runs will only need to run fewer calculations, then apply their values as an "increment/decrement"

### `balance` table after running for rows 0-1

| user | item | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user0 | item1 | 1 |
| user1 | item1 | -1 |
| ... | ... | ... |

### `balance` table after running for rows 2-3

| user | item | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user0 | item1 | 0 |
| user1 | item1 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

How can i run this calculation in an iterative way, and not require a truncation of the `balance` table?

Comment: You may check this post: [Refresh materalized view incrementally in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86779/refresh-materalized-view-incrementally-in-postgresql). Looks like it is still not implemented

Comment: Your description is not very clear, but you can use logical decoding to capture changes to a table to catch up.

Comment: Refreshing materialized view incrementally sounds promising, however the size of the table may prevent this from being feasible. If i could to bound the query to calculate rows 0-9 on the first run, then 10-19 on the second i could operate much quicker between runs... an entire table calculation takes ~8min.